# How to get read latency in cassandra 1.1?

Tags: cassandra, opscenter

With the command: 
nodetool cfstats

I was able to see the statistics of each keyspace and column family. But there are so many column family with their Read Latency displayed as NaN ms. I want to monitor the Read Latency of Cassandra but I am not sure how to get the correct data.

PS: It would be nice if someone can explain to me how OpsCenter calculates the Read Latency on Cassandra 1.1

Comment: do you have anything generating the reads to all the columns families having the values displayed as NaN?

Comment: I am not sure. But I guess my main concern is I am not sure how Read Latency is being calculated when there are so many column family.

Comment: Could you please attach the screenshot of what are you looking at so I can be sure I'm addressing the right thing?

Comment: Ok, my real question is how to get the Read Latency(a number) in microseconds on Cassandra 1.1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to monitor the latency of your Cassandra cluster is by looking at it from your application's perspective. This has an advantage and disadvantage:

Advantage is that it is easy to instrument your application code and put a timer around Cassandra calls and log the measurement somewhere for graphing or simply push it to your graphing tool.

Disadvantage is that it will not be Cassandra's absolute latency and it will include network and application latency too.

The numbers reported by cfstats are divided into ranges which seems it is not something you want. You see NaN because those CFs are not receiving enough reads for the counters to populate. Hence,  the best way to get the latency numbers is to instrument Cassandra code a little bit more. Here is a diff based on Cassandra 1.1.10 that I have which adds latency logging for some operations. It will log the absolute latency seen by the coordinator node before it returns to the client, so your would know exactly how your Cassandra node did:

https://github.com/aryanet/cassandra/commits/ag-cassandra-1.1.10